# Intensity of an electron beam as slits are opened

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

An electron beam strikes a barrier with one slit, and the resulting electron flux through the slit is detected. Then, two identical slits are opened on opposite sides of the original slit, both equally "illuminated" by the beam. What will be the flux at the center slit now? Does this answer imply that three times as many electrons pass through three slits than through one?

I am beginning quantum mechanics and this question is confusing me greatly. My first thought was that the flux will be nine times as great, since intensity is proportional to the square of the amplitude, which has tripled (three times as many slits). However, if nothing about the electron beam changes, how can the flux change by simply adding more slits? Thank you for reading.